# Show that $L[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a $L$-vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L$ be a field and $p(x) \in L[x]$ with degree of $p(x)=n>0$ show that $L[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a $L$-vector space of dimension $n$

My try:

We can see any element $x \in L$ as a polynomial of degree $0$
then $L[x]/<p(x)>$ is a extension of L then $L[x]/<p(x)>$ is a L-vector space

Now let be $f(x) \in L[x]$ then $f(x)= p(x)q(x)+r(x)$ with degree of $r(x)<q(x)$

and then $f(x) \equiv r(x) $ mod $p(x)$

because $f(x)= a_0x+,...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n}x^{n}+...+a_kx^k=a_0x+,...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+(a_nx+,...,+a_kx^{k-x})$
and then $\lbrace 1,x,...,x^{n-1} \rbrace$ form a basis and then $L[x]/<p(x)>$ over L has dimension n, is this right?

Comment: It is correct. But you might want to introduce a notation that distinguishes elements in the quotient with the elements in the ring $L[x]$. Like $\{\bar{1},\bar{x},...,\bar{x}^{n-1}\}$ would be okay I guess.

Comment: Although the intention of your try is clear, it is rather sloppily formulated. What is definitely missing is an argument that $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^{n-1}$ are linearly independent.